# How do I clear or delete all elements in an SplStack?

Tags: php, list, stack

The [SplStack](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splstack.php) has many functions for accessing its elements, but is there a way to clear it?  Or should I "clear" my stack by replacing it with a new, empty stack?

Comment: The same way you would clear an array: a series of pops() or unsets(), or unset the stack itself and create a new stack

Comment: yup. just create a new stack.

Comment: @MarkBaker, want to write an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in method to clear a stack.

You'd either need to clear it down using pops or unsets:

```
while($stack->valid()) {
    $stack->pop();
}
```

Or unset the stack itself, and create a new one:

```
unset($stack);
$stack = new \SplStack();
```